# DER certificate fingerprint is different with openssl [keystore]

Tags: java, security, openssl, certificate, keytool

Hello I have keystore generated 3 years ago. Everything was working until now.
Current situation:
We are using VSTS to build our app in Xamarin but it requires latest version of java(8).
The `.keystore` file contains certificate with sha1 fingerprint starting `67:22:60..`
So we wanted to move the certificate to new keystore generated under java8, using `kse` or `keytool` but we ended up with the certificate which has different finger print like `36:99:09`

Commands used:
`keytool -export -alias 1 -file mydomain.crt -keystore old.jks`
 `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias 1 -file mydomain.crt -keystore new.jks`

Even if I view the certificate with windows viewer it says `thumbprint: 67:22:60..`

I tried to fix this with `openssl` but it seems to be used by `kse` as well because when I tried to view fingerprint with 
`openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in mydomain.crt -sha1 -inform der` then the resul was `36:99:09`.

Is there any way to fix it?